# Base64 decoding error in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to decode a base64 string with `#ToString( ToBinary( stringToDecode  ) )#` and coldfusion gives an error saying the parameter must be a base-64 encoded string. The string comes from a third party, and is supposed to be a pdf file. Here is a part of it:

```
JVBERi0xLjUKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvUmVzb3VyY2VzPDw+Pi9TdWJ0 eXBlL0Zvcm0vQkJveFswIDAgMTUuNDQgMTUuNDZdL01hdHJpeCBbMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL0xlbmd0 aCAyMi9Gb3JtVHlwZSAxL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZT4+c3RyZWFtCk9lHxbaEDXZpIO1A/Gj mGuxQdW3qkgKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdC9SZXNvdXJj ZXM8PD4+L1N1YnR5cGUvRm9ybS9CQm94WzAgMCAxNS40NCAxNS4xOV0vTWF0cml4IFsxIDAgMCAx IDAgMF0vTGVuZ3RoIDIyL0Zvcm1UeXBlIDEvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlPj5zdHJlYW0KtDN8 NkUKYx04Gj8V9LfOboGvN9VRIgplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZS9YT2Jq ZWN0L1Jlc291cmNlczw8Pj4vU3VidHlwZS9Gb3JtL0JCb3hbMCAwIDE1LjQ0IDE1LjcyXS9NYXRy aXggWzEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9MZW5ndGggMjIvRm9ybVR5cGUgMS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGU+
```

What I had thought was the spaces were a problem, but I did a replace to replace all " " with "" and they are still in there. Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: @haxtbh I tried to close that as too broad; before I didn't know the encoding and now I know it's base64.

Comment: Did you have a look at this page?  https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/binarydecode.html   it looks like you are trying convert a string to binary and back to a string again in your example above.

Comment: @RandyJohnson this tells me the input and output strings are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my testing I can take a local pdf and convert it to a string to mimic the string you are getting from the API.  I can then take it and convert it back to a PDF.

When I use the string you put above I cannot get it to work.  Not sure if something is list from you pasting it here or not.

Here is my code, maybe you can alter it to use the string right from the api.

```
<cffile action="readbinary" file="#expandPath('./test.pdf')#" variable="thefile"/>

<cfset the_string = toString(theFile)/>

<cfscript>
patrick_string = ToBase64("JVBERi0xLjUKJeLjz9MKMSAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvUmVzb3VyY2VzPDw+Pi9TdWJ0 eXBlL0Zvcm0vQkJveFswIDAgMTUuNDQgMTUuNDZdL01hdHJpeCBbMSAwIDAgMSAwIDBdL0xlbmd0 aCAyMi9Gb3JtVHlwZSAxL0ZpbHRlci9GbGF0ZURlY29kZT4+c3RyZWFtCk9lHxbaEDXZpIO1A/Gj mGuxQdW3qkgKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iagoyIDAgb2JqCjw8L1R5cGUvWE9iamVjdC9SZXNvdXJj ZXM8PD4+L1N1YnR5cGUvRm9ybS9CQm94WzAgMCAxNS40NCAxNS4xOV0vTWF0cml4IFsxIDAgMCAx IDAgMF0vTGVuZ3RoIDIyL0Zvcm1UeXBlIDEvRmlsdGVyL0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlPj5zdHJlYW0KtDN8 NkUKYx04Gj8V9LfOboGvN9VRIgplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmoKPDwvVHlwZS9YT2Jq ZWN0L1Jlc291cmNlczw8Pj4vU3VidHlwZS9Gb3JtL0JCb3hbMCAwIDE1LjQ0IDE1LjcyXS9NYXRy aXggWzEgMCAwIDEgMCAwXS9MZW5ndGggMjIvRm9ybVR5cGUgMS9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGU+");

string2 = toBinary(ToBase64(the_string));

binencode=BinaryEncode(string2, "Base64"); 

</cfscript>


<cffile action="write" file="#expandPath('./randy.pdf')#" output="#thefile#" addnewline="No" />

<a href="randy.pdf">click</a>
```

Updated Code:

```
<cffile action="readbinary" file="#expandPath('./test.pdf')#" variable="thefile"/>

<cfset the_string = toBase64(theFile)/>

<cfscript>

string2 = toBinary(the_string);

</cfscript>


<cffile action="write" file="#expandPath('./randy.pdf')#" output="#string2#" addnewline="No" />

<a href="randy.pdf">click</a>
```

Comment: I would like to paste the entire string for you to fully replicate my issue, but it's too large to put in my question (my browser freezes if I paste it in the question editor) Is there a repository I can place it in?

Comment: You should be able to alter my code to see if you can get it working.  Comment out the cffile and do a <cfset thefile="STRING CONTENT"/> and it should run for you.

Comment: a better idea may be to save the string to a file and do a cffile read when testing so you don't have the 300kb of text in your code file.

Comment: I think you have a mistake in your code, variable #thefile# is read, then put into another pdf, the string result isn't written to the file.

Comment: <cfset the_string = toString(theFile)/> puts the pdf to a string to mimic your api output.  These 2 lines convert it back to a pdf string2 = toBinary(ToBase64(the_string));

binencode=BinaryEncode(string2, "Base64");

Comment: Right but `<cffile output = "#thefile#"` uses an unchanged value.

Comment: You are right.  Dang lol.  I will take a look shortly when I get back from lunch.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated cfscript way of doing it in case anyone is interested:

```
<cfscript>
// read the binary file and save it as a variable
myPdf = fileReadBinary( expandPath( "/test.pdf" ) );

// encode as base64
myPdf = toBase64( myPdf );

// output the base64 version to the browser
writedump( myPdf );

// convert back to binary
myPdf = toBinary( myPdf );

// write to a new PDF file
fileWrite( expandPath( "/new.pdf" ), myPdf );
</cfscript>
```